# Lexical cast Partial conversion - Is it possible?

Tags: c++, boost

`lexical_cast` throws an exception in the following case. Is there a way to use `lexical_cast` and convert the string to integer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/lexical_cast.hpp"
#include <string>
int main()
{
        std::string src = "124is";
        int iNumber = boost::lexical_cast<int>(src);
        std::cout << "After conversion " << iNumber << std::endl;
}
```

I understand, I can use `atoi` instead of `boost::lexical_cast`.

Comment: `std::stoi` should do it.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Let me try.

Comment: Do you have some requirement that prevents you from preprocessing the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your requirements correctly it seems as though removing the non-numeric elements from the string first before the `lexical_cast` will solve your problem. The approach I outline here makes use of the isdigit function which will return true if the given `char` is a digit from 0 to 9.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/lexical_cast.hpp"
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype> //for isdigit

struct is_not_digit{
    bool operator()(char a) { return !isdigit(a); }
};

int main()
{
    std::string src = "124is";
    src.erase(std::remove_if(src.begin(),src.end(),is_not_digit()),src.end());
    int iNumber = boost::lexical_cast<int>(src);
    std::cout << "After conversion " << iNumber << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The boost/lexical_cast uses stringstream to convert from string to other types,so you must make sure the string can be converted completely！ or， it will throw the bad_lexical_cast exception,This is an example:

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

#include <iostream>

#include <string> 

#define ERROR_LEXICAL_CAST     1 

int main()

{

    using boost::lexical_cast;

    int         a = 0;

    double        b = 0.0;

    std::string s = ""; 

    int            e = 0;    

    try

    { 

        // ----- string --> int 

        a = lexical_cast<int>("123");//good

        b = lexical_cast<double>("123.12");//good


        // -----double to string good

        s = lexical_cast<std::string>("123456.7"); 

        // ----- bad

        e = lexical_cast<int>("abc");

    }

    catch(boost::bad_lexical_cast& e)

    {

        // bad lexical cast: source type value could not be interpreted as target

        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;

        return ERROR_LEXICAL_CAST;

    } 



    std::cout << a << std::endl;    // cout：123 

    std::cout << b << std::endl;    //cout：123.12 

    std::cout << s << std::endl;     //cout：123456.7 

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: you are welcome!I am also not very familiar with boost!I think boost is worth to learn carefully!!go together!